# How to automate my SSH activities on remote machine

Tags: python, git, bash, ssh, deployment

I have more than a dozen machines where I had to perform almost similar activities:

- Log onto ssh: `ssh mymachine.com`
- CD to a path `cd to/my/path`
- Run git pull `git pull origin master`
- Some kind of setting file where I can mention which `.py` file I run.
- From last step, Execute Script `time python {script_file}`

How can I automate it? Can BASH do that or some other deployment tool can do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could do this with Bash scripts, I highly recommend taking a look at [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/).

> Fabric is a Python (2.5-2.7) library and command-line tool for streamlining the use of SSH for application deployment or systems administration tasks.

Harry Percival [shows a good example of how to use it in one chapter of his excellent book](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/ch09.html).

Comment: No Py3 version :/

Comment: There is a fork that seems reliable: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fabric3

Answer (score 0):

Just pipe the commands you want to ssh, and it will execute them at the remote server:

```
cat script.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo "I am $USER at $(hostname)"

$ ssh user@host < script.sh
```

If you want to use local variables, you can user the HEREDOC syntax:

```
ssh user@host << EOF
  echo "I am \$USER at \$(hostname), called from $USER at $(hostname)"
EOF
```

Comment: In more complex cases, you can even use the output of a function so that you can easily tailor the actual commands issued based on some configuration file, arguments, etc.

Comment: This assumes `script.sh` itself never reads from standard input.

Comment: @chepner: The tasks listed in the OP could probably be done without reading stdin, but do you know of a better way that would allow for reading stdin from the script?

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [Sparrowdo](https://github.com/melezhik/sparrowdo) a tool for easy ssh/bash automation. There are a lot of plugins, functions ready for usage.

PS. Disclosure -  I am the tool author